# Troubleshooting php form submition blank fields in emails

Tags: php, forms, email

I know this question has been asked before, I have researched but can't seem to get to the route of the problem. I'm hoping someone can help. Ok so form seems to be working in as much as the form has to be completed before it allows to be sent, the form sends and an email arrives. Unfortunately the email fields are blank.

So here's the php:

```
<?php

$Body  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$Body .= 'Content-type: text/html; ch***t=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$Body .= 'From: '. $EmailFrom . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$EmailFrom = "info@mywebsite.com";
$EmailTo = "info@mywebsite.com";
$Subject = "Contact Form";
$Name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
echo "please check your details";
header("Location: http://mywebsite.com/formredirect.html");
exit;
}

// prepare email body text

$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom" . "\r\n");

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=formredirect.htm\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contact" id="contact">
                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="submit"></a>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

I appreciate it's probably me being really dense. I'm new to this so am fumbling my way around. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$validationOK=true;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` keys are **CaSe SenSitIve**

`$_POST['Name']` is different from `$_POST['name']`

Either change the form `name` attribute or the `POST keys` so they match, i.e.:

**FORM**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
...
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
...
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
...
```

---

**PHP**

```
...
$Name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$Email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
...
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so very much! You are a wonderful person. This has solved the issue. With regards to your comment regarding the '$validationOK=true;' and what was I trying to achieve with that. I'll be honest, I have absolutely no idea! I did not write the php code, I simply edited some that was given to me by my web hosting company. Like I said, I am new to this and really know very little! Your help has been invaluable. Thank you!